# generate_subscripts(array, 2) returns two records when there is only one multidimensional element

Tags: postgresql, multidimensional-array, set-returning-functions

Why does this  return 2 records when there is only one multidimensional element in multidimensional array `images`?

```
SELECT images
FROM  (
   SELECT images, generate_subscripts(images, 2) AS s
   FROM listings
   WHERE listings.id = 2
   ) as foo;
```

Note: I shortened the base64 string for easier viewing.

```
id               | 2
created_at       | 2017-04-19 23:44:50.150913+00
posted_by        | 10209280753550922
images           | {{/9j/4AAJRgAB2dgKd/9k=,3/2/image-3-2-1492645490308.jpeg}}
```

---

```
dev_dolphin_db=# SELECT images FROM(SELECT images, generate_subscripts(images, 2) AS s FROM listings where listings.id = 2) as foo;
-[ RECORD 1 ]----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
images | {{/9j/4AAQSkZJRdgKd/9k=,3/2/image-3-2-1492645490308.jpeg}}
-[ RECORD 2 ]----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
images | {{/9j/4AAQSkZN2dgKd/9k=,3/2/image-3-2-1492645490308.jpeg}}
```

Comment: yes, sorry! don't know how this one slipped by without my answer mark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are ***two*** elements in your array, separated by the comma:

```
{{/9j/4AAJRgAB2dgKd/9k=,3/2/image-3-2-1492645490308.jpeg}}
```

See:

```
SELECT *
FROM unnest('{{/9j/4AAJRgAB2dgKd/9k=,3/2/image-3-2-1492645490308.jpeg}}'::text[])

unnest
--------------------------------
/9j/4AAJRgAB2dgKd/9k=
3/2/image-3-2-1492645490308.jpeg
```

[`generate_subscripts()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-srf.html#FUNCTIONS-SRF-SUBSCRIPTS) returns one row per element in the specified dimension (not one row per dimension). [The manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-srf.html#FUNCTIONS-SRF-SUBSCRIPTS):

> `generate_subscripts` is a convenience function that generates the set
>   of valid subscripts for the specified dimension of the given array.
>   Zero rows are returned for arrays that do not have the requested
>   dimension, or for NULL arrays (but valid subscripts are returned for
>   NULL array elements).

If that's supposed to be a *single* element, it would have to be double-quoted to escape the special meaning of the comma:

```
{{"/9j/4AAJRgAB2dgKd/9k=,3/2/image-3-2-1492645490308.jpeg"}}
```

Aside: in modern Postgres you can use this simpler equivalent query:

```
SELECT images
FROM   listings, generate_subscripts(images, 2) s
WHERE  id = 2;
```

That's an implicit `CROSS JOIN LATERAL`. See:

- [What is the difference between LATERAL and a subquery in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28550679/what-is-the-difference-between-lateral-and-a-subquery-in-postgresql/28557803#28557803)